# Kivymd mdspinner is slowing down backend

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy, kivymd

I am creating a desktop app that will allow users to input text to text inputs on a GUI and will then write those values to a cutsheet (excel spreadsheet). I am using mdspinner to give some indication that the function is running in the background, which will then disappear, and a checkmark icon will appear to signify that the values have been written to the spreadsheet.

The issue is that the mdspinner significantly slows down the execution of the code that writes the text input to the spreadsheet. Without the spinner it takes less than 10 seconds to complete, but it takes well over a minute when using the spinner.

Here is a snippet showing how I am calling the function:

```
def SingleSave(self):
    threading.Thread(target=writecutsheet.main.SingleSave, args=(self)).start()
    self.spinner_start()

def spinner_start(self):
    self.root.ids.spinid.active = True
```

I am using threading to prevent the GUI from freezing when making the callback. The thread then calls a function (SingleSave) in a split file (writecutsheet). I have then added a line in the function in the split file to stop the spinner, to prevent it from stopping before the thread completes.

Here is the KV for the spinner and the button to call it:

```
        FloatLayout:
            TickIcon:
                id: complete
            LoadingIcon:
                id: loading
            MDSpinner:
                size_hint: None, None
                id: prog1
                size: dp(46), dp(46)
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "center_x": 0.94}
                active: False      
        FloatLayout:
            MDNavigationRail:
                NavHomeButton:
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "Landing"
                        screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                NavSaveButton:
                    on_press:
                        app.SingleSave()
                        complete.icon: ""
                NavGenerateButton:
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "Generate"
                        screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                NavSettingsButton:
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "Settings"
                        screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

I think I have tried everything at this point, including, starting a thread for the spinner function as well as the SingleSave function, just adding, prog1.active = True, to the KV, triggered when the save button is pressed, placing it directly into the split files etc., but nothing works.

I must add that I am new to threading, so I have a feeling that I am messing something up there.

I have only provided snippets of the code as there would be a lot to sanitize to provide a working example, but if you need more to go on (which I suspect you will), I can provide working examples of all the files.

---

I created a minimal running example and stripped out a lot of the actual functionality and replaced it with a for loop to print numbers 1-1000. The actual single save function is a for loop to read entries from a dictionary which contains the text input ID, x and y co-ords for the excel sheet, and sheetname. The for loop calls another function in the same split file (to write to the cutsheet) for every item in the dictionary. I know this is different from the example provided, but the slow down is still present with the simple for loop in my example.

It should run immediately when starting the app. You will notice that when you commend out the code to start and stop the spinner, the function completes almost immediately.

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.navigationrail import MDNavigationRail
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory  # NOQA: F401
from kivy.loader import Loader
from kivymd import images_path
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import HoverBehavior
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.base import ExceptionHandler, ExceptionManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.animation import Animation
import writecutsheets
import threading
Window.maximize()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
            self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
            return Builder.load_file('myapp.kv')

    def SingleSave(self, screenid, spinid, tickid):
        reset = "self.root.ids." + tickid + ".icon = \"\""
        exec(reset)
        threading.Thread(target=writecutsheets.main.SingleSave, args=(self, screenid, spinid, tickid, )).start()
        spinner_string = "self.root.ids." + spinid + ".active = True"
        exec(spinner_string)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

writecutsheets.py:

```
class main:  
    def SingleSave(self, screenid, spinid, tickid):
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            print(i)
        spinner_string = "self.root.ids." + spinid + ".active = False"
        exec(spinner_string)
        complete_string = "self.root.ids." + tickid + ".icon = \"check\""
        exec(complete_string)
```

myapp.kv:

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import toast kivymd.toast.toast
#:import StiffScrollEffect kivymd.effects.stiffscroll.StiffScrollEffect
#:import Snackbar kivymd.uix.snackbar.Snackbar
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#:import threading threading

<NavSaveButton@MDNavigationRailItem>
    icon: "content-save-outline"
<NavGenerateButton@MDNavigationRailItem>
    icon: "check-circle-outline"
<NavSettingsButton@MDNavigationRailItem>
    icon: "cog-outline"
<NavHomeButton@MDNavigationRailItem>
    icon: "home"

##### Navigation Drawer Buttons #####
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    text_color: text_color
    icon_color: text_color

##### Button for Dropdown menus #####
<DropDownButton@MDFillRoundFlatIconButton>
    size_hint_x: .2
    icon: "menu-down"
    text: "Select an option"

##### Title text for each screen #####
<TitleLabel@MDLabel>
    halign: "center"
    font_style: "H3"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.85}

##### Text Input #####
<Textbox@MDTextField>
    size_hint_x: .2
    write_tab: False

<TickIcon@MDIconButton>
    icon: ""
    icon_size: "40sp"
    theme_icon_color: "Custom"
    icon_color: "#00ff00"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "center_x": 0.94}


##### Icon for help text #####
<HelpIcon@MDIconButton+MDTooltip>
    icon: "help-circle-outline"
    icon_size: "16sp"

##### Icon for writing values on given page #####
<SaveButton@MDIconButton>
    icon: "content-save-outline"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.98, "center_x": 0.94}

##### Icon to navigate to the generate CLI screen #####
<CompleteButton@MDIconButton>
    icon: "check-circle-outline"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.98, "center_x": 0.96}
    theme_icon_color: "Custom"
    icon_color: "#00ff00"

##### Checkbox #####
<Check@MDCheckbox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "38dp", "38dp"

##### Grid Layout #####
<Grid@MDGridLayout>
    col: 1
    rows: 1
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.85}

##### Icon button for going back #####
<BackButton@MDIconButton+MDTooltip>
    icon: "arrow-left"
    tooltip_text: "Back"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.08, "center_x": 0.1}

##### Icon button for moving forward #####
<ForwardButton@MDIconButton+MDTooltip>
    tooltip_text: "Next"
    icon: "arrow-right"
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.08, "center_x": 0.94}

##### Scrollview Template ######
<Scroll@ScrollView>
    scroll_y: 1
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.3}
    do_scroll_x: False

##### Toolbar Template #####
<Toolbar@MDToolbar>
    title: "Perimeta Config Generator"
    elevation: 10
    pos_hint: {"top": 1}


MDNavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout
    Toolbar:
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: "screen1"
            Grid:
                TitleLabel:
                    text: "My screen"
            Scroll:
                FloatLayout:
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Network Name"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.95, "center_x": 0.8}
                    HelpIcon:
                        tooltip_text: "Enter the name of yournetwork"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.95, "center_x": 0.29}
                    DropDownButton:
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.95, "center_x": 0.6}
                        id: servnetname
                        on_release:
                            app.servdropdown(servnetname)
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Source Description"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "center_x": 0.8}
                    HelpIcon:
                        tooltip_text: "Enter the description of thesource"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "center_x": 0.29}
                    Textbox:
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.91, "center_x": 0.6}
                        id: tsdesc
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "IP Version"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.85, "center_x": 0.8}
                    HelpIcon:
                        tooltip_text: "Enter the IP Version"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.85, "center_x": 0.29}
                    DropDownButton:
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.85, "center_x": 0.6}
                        id: ipversts
                        on_release:
                            app.ipdropdown(ipversts)
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Start IP"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.8, "center_x": 0.8}
                    HelpIcon:
                        tooltip_text: ""
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.8, "center_x": 0.29}
                    Textbox:
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.81, "center_x": 0.6}
                        id: trustip
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "End IP"
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.75, "center_x": 0.8}
                    HelpIcon:
                        tooltip_text: ""
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.75, "center_x": 0.29}
                    Textbox:
                        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.76, "center_x": 0.6}
                        id: rangeendts
            FloatLayout:
                TickIcon:
                    id: complete3
                MDSpinner:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    id: prog3
                    size: dp(46), dp(46)
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "center_x": 0.94}
                    active: False
            FloatLayout:
                size_hint_y: 0.936
                MDNavigationRail:
                    NavSaveButton:
                        on_press:
                            app.SingleSave(3, "prog3", "complete3")
                    NavGenerateButton:
                        on_release:
                            screen_manager.current = "Generate"
                            screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    NavSettingsButton:
                        on_release:
                            screen_manager.current = "Settings"
                            screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        MDNavigationDrawerMenu:   
            MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                text: "Basic Configuration"
                title_color: text_color
                title_color: text_color 
            DrawerClickableItem:
                icon: ""                
                text: "Start"
                on_press:
                    nav_drawer.set_state("close")
```

Comment: Post minimal runnable example

Comment: Minimal example added

Comment: It is not minimal example and i cant run it...

Comment: Please provide some more detail as to why this is not minimal and why you can't run it (i.e. what error are you seeing)? I am new to stack overflow and coding as a whole, and I can't improve if I don't know what to improve.